# Prove that $\frac {AN}{ND}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{AM}{MD}$ elementary.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, projective-geometry

> Let $\triangle ABC$, $D\in BC, M\in AD$, $BM\cap AC=\{E\}, CM\cap AB=\{F\}, EF\cap AD=\{N\}$.
> Prove that $$\dfrac {AN}{ND}=\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{AM}{MD}$$

Now I have a projective solution and I would like to get nice elementary solution.

[image]

Projective solution: Let $EF$ meet $BC$ at $X$ and let it meet $AB$ and $AC$ at $G$ and $H$ respectively. Then

\begin{align} (A,D;M,N)&= (XA,XD;XM,XN)\\
&= (XA,XB;XG,XF)\\
&= (A,B;G,F)\\
&= (MA,MB;MG,MF)\\
&= (MA,ME;MH,MC)\\
&= (A,E;H,C)\\
&= (XA,XE;XH,XC)\\
&= (XA,XN;XM,XD)\\
&= (A,N;M,D)
\end{align}

So we have $${AM\over MD}:{AN \over ND} = {AM\over MN}:{AD \over DN}$$ and thus $$AN\cdot MD = AD\cdot MN \implies xz=y(x+y+z)$$
which is equivalent to formula we want.

---

Interesting note: If we move $M$ on $AD$ point $X$ is fixed:

> By Menelaus theorem for triangle $ABC$ and transversal $X-F-E$ we have $${BX\over XC}\cdot {AF\over FB}\cdot {CE\over AE} =1\;\;\;/\cdot{CD\over DB}$$
>
> so we have by Ceva theorem for $ABC$ and $M$:
>
>  $${BX\over XC}\cdot \underbrace{{AF\over FB}\cdot {CE\over AE}\cdot{CD\over DB}}_{=1} ={CD\over DB}$$
>
> So we see that as we move $M$ (and $N,E,F$) point $X$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is purely projective in nature, so a solution may need to use projective arguments. I am trying to reduce them to a minimum, using only Menelaus and a simple property of the cross ratio, namely the relation between $(S,T,U,V)$ and $(S,U,T,V)$ on a line, which may be shown using cartesian coordinates on the line.

We apply Menelaus in:

- triangle $\Delta ADC$ with "secant" line $XNE$, and
- triangle $\Delta ADC$ with "secant" line $BME$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
1=\frac 11&=
\frac
{\displaystyle 
\frac{NA}{ND}\cdot
\frac{XD}{XC}\cdot
\color{gray}{\frac{EC}{EA}}
}
{\displaystyle
\frac{MA}{MD}\cdot
\frac{BD}{BC}\cdot
\color{gray}{\frac{EC}{EA}}
 }
=
\frac
{\displaystyle 
\frac{NA}{ND}:\frac{MA}{MD}
}
{\displaystyle
\frac{BD}{BC}:\frac{XD}{XC}
 }
\ ,
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{ and the denominator in the above fraction is:}
\\
\frac{BD}{BC}:\frac{XD}{XC}
&=(B,X,D,C)
=\frac 1{(X,B,D,C)}
=\frac 1{1-(X,D,B,C)}
\\
&=\frac 1{1-(-1)}=\frac 12\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the numerator in the same fraction is also $\frac 12$.

Here, we have used the fact that the $4$-tuple $(X,D;B,C)$ is harmonic. This can be shown by using Ceva and Menelaus for $\Delta ABC$ (for the cevians through $M$, and respectively for the "secant" line $XEF$.

$\square$

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: some observations in figure: The figure is constructed such that $AM=MD$ and $AD\bot BC$, $BE\bot AC$ and $CF\bot AB$.

$\triangle MEF\sim \triangle MBC$

$\angle AFE=\angle ACB\Rightarrow \triangle AEF\sim \triangle ABC$

But it does not look that $\frac{AN}{ND}=\frac 12 \cdot \frac {AM}{MD}$

Using similarities we may find $\frac{AN}{ND}=\frac 1 k \cdot \frac {AM}{MD}$

The figure shows $k\neq 2$